# How to find an optimal sequence of merging operations?

Tags: co.combinatorics, ds.dynamical-systems, oc.optimization-and-control, combinatorial-optimization, approximation-algorithms

Given a set of items, each characterized by a quality $q_i\in(0,1)$. We can merge two items of quality $q_i$ and $q_j$ to a single item $k$ of quality $q_k=f(q_i,q_j)$, where $f$ is increasing in $q_i$ and $q_j$. Suppose that initially we have $n$ items of identical quality $q$, I want to obtain a final item of maximal quality, by a set of merging operations. How to find an optimal sequence of merging operations?

For example, if we have $4$ items, we can merge $1$ and $2$ to a new item $a$, $3$ and $4$ to a new item $b$, and then merge $a$ and $b$ to the final item; we can also merge $1$ and $2$ to item $a$ and then merge $a$ and $3$ to a new item and then merge it with $4$ to a final item. Has this problem been explored before mathematically?

Let me give two examples of $f$.

1. $f(x,y)=\frac{xy}{xy+(1−x)(1−y)}$. This function is commutative and associative (as a binary operation) so the quality of the final merged item is independent of the merge sequence;
2. $f(x,y)=\frac{10xy−(x+y)+1}{8xy−2(x+y)+5}$. In this case, what is the optimal merge sequence?

Comment: Is the only thing known of $f$ that it is increasing?

Comment: @JukkaKohonen $f$ may have a complex form. As I am interested in solving the generic case, so I am not targeting a particular $f$. Let's assume that $f$ is increasing and, if that may help, concave in $q_i,q_j$.

Comment: At each step, is the number of items reduced by only $1$?

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo Yes, each time we can merge 2 items into another item of better quality. If we choose to gradually merge all items, finally we will get a single item. Please refer to my comment of the answer below for more information on $f$.

Comment: [Semi-naive implementation](https://gist.github.com/pjt33/c9c1c765629f09264e89dbdd5301c0e9) (can be run online at https://tio.run/#python3-pypy ). There seem to be a variety of tree shapes obtained.

Answer (score 1):

This is only about the smallest nontrivial case $n=3$ but too long for a comment. Writing it here because it may help in thinking about the bigger cases.

If $n=3$, exact optimum is required, and $f$ is only known to be increasing and symmetric, it is not possible with less than exhaustive trial of all three possible merging trees.

Suppose $q_1=0.01$, $q_2=0.02$ and $q_3=0.03$, and further
$$
q_{1,2} = f(0.01,0.02) = 0.1, \\
q_{1,3} = f(0.01,0.03) = 0.2, \\
q_{2,3} = f(0.02,0.03) = 0.3,
$$
where $q_{i,j}$ is the quality obtained by merging $i$ and $j$.

Now there are three possible merging sequences (up to symmetry), and without further knowledge of $f$, it is not possible to know which one has the best quality:
$$
q_{(1,2),3} = f(0.1, 0.03) = \;? \\
q_{(1,3),2} = f(0.2, 0.02) = \;? \\
q_{(2,3),1} = f(0.3, 0.01) = \;? \\
$$
By a suitable choice of an increasing function $f$, it is possible to choose any one of them to be the biggest.

Comment: Thank you for your response. Let me provide more information on $f$. We can assume that all the quality $q_i\in [a,1]$ with $a\in(0.5,1)$ being a threshold. $f(x,y)$ is symmetrical in $x$ and $y$ and concave in $x$ (and $y$). $f(x,1)=1$, $f(x,y)>x$ for $x\ge a$. Can we have some tractable insight?

Comment: @lchen That helps a bit but not too much. What may really help is to know what your $f$ is (or to what parametric family it belongs, if it is a parametric family). Then one can play some games and, perhaps, come up with a meaningful answer. In full generality the problem is hardly tractable...

Comment: @fedja Let me give two examples of $f$. (1) $f(x,y)=\frac{xy}{xy+(1-x)(1-y)}$. This function is abelian so the quality of the final merged item is independent of the merge sequence; (2) $f(x,y)=\frac{10xy-3(x+y)+1}{8xy-6(x+y)+5}$. In this case, what is the optimal merge sequence.

Comment: @Ichen I guess you mean the first function is commutative and associative (as a binary operation)

Comment: @Ichen, the second of those weight merging functions doesn't respect the desired properties. E.g. it has poles at $(0.5, 1)$ and $(1, 0.5)$, and $f(1,1) = 5 \neq 1$.

Comment: @PeterTaylor Thank you for pointing out the problem in case 2. It should be $f(x,y)=\frac{10xy-(x+y)+1}{8xy-2(x+y)+5}$

Comment: @lchen I still wouldn't say that in the second case $f(x,1)=1$ (for some reason $(9x)/(6x+3)$ fails to properly cancel in my mind) and in the first case $f(x,y)<x$, not $>x$, as required. I guess I've got the general idea nevertheless, but an example consistent with the declared properties (if you do not want to abandon them) would still be helpful :-)

Comment: @lchen Also, I should say that while it is theoretically quite interesting, it is rather trivial in terms of programming: the corresponding maxima $m_n$ satisfy the recurrence relation $m_1=q$, $m_n=\max_{1\le k\le [n/2]}f(m_k,m_{n-k})$, which runs in time $n^2$.

Comment: @fedja Thank you for the insightful comments, but I did not precisely catch your recurrent scheme. Given its mathematical intractability, let me pose my problem algorithmically: we have a set of $n$ items, each with quality $q_i$, find a merging algorithm generating a single item of maximal quality (we my discard some initial items). Could you pls sketch your scheme?

Comment: @lchen It doesn't (and has never been intended to) work for different $q_i$! Initially you requested the initial values to be all the same, which makes the maxima depend only on the cardinality of the merged subset, not on the subset itself. Then the scheme is exactly as defined. Otherwise one has to go over all trees, indeed.

Comment: @fedja If $q_i=q$ initially, could you sketch the scheme in this case?

Comment: @lchen What is unclear about the recurrence relation I wrote?

Comment: @fedja I see. Thank you.